# Google Admin SDK - Directory API - Cannot find how to set group properties such as "Who can join group" or "Who can post"

Tags: api, google-admin-sdk

I am using the Google Directory API for creating groups (see the reference here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/insert)

I can create a group just fine but I cannot find where I can set properties for the group such as "Who can join group" or "Who can post" as defined here: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/10376887

Those properties are accessible from the web interface but do not seem to be available via the API which is a shame.

If anyone know an API that could allow me to manage Google Groups properties please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out there was a dedicated API for this which is https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/get